# Matching regular expression in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to test string like `{"count":0}` in Scala using `matches`. Since Integer part can be different I am trying to do something like this:

```
assert(response.matches(s"^\\{\"count\":${notificationCount}\\}$"), s"Actual response: $response")
```

But I am getting wrong string literal in second `$` sign which indicate end of string in regular expression.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is that `$` a literal, or EOS ? If literal, just escape it `"\\$"`. Also, the regex has count quoted, so the engine sees `^\{"count":0\}$` If you think there is spaces, add `\s*` between `^\{"count":\s*0\}$`

Comment: `$` is EOS so even I put `//$` IntelliJ is complaing "Wrong String literal"

Comment: Normally, languages won't interpolate the dollar sign as a string variable, unless it absolutely clear it is a variable, and it is defined. I guess in this case its `${var}`, but it's usually pretty clear during interpolation, escaped characters, are, well, literals. Something else must be wrong. Check the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using string interpolation in Scala, you can escape `$` by using a double `$$`:

```
val foo = 5
s"$foo${foo + 1}$$" //56$
```

You might also consider using a triple-quoted raw string to help with the escaped brace and quote characters:

```
s"""{"count":${foo}}$$""" //{"count":5}$
```

Comment: $ is EOS for regular expression.

Comment: Right, but when using string interpolation `$` is also how you interpolate a variable or code block.  So it needs to be escaped when building a regex using string interpolation, and you can escape it using `$$`, so that the regex you are building can actually end in the EOS character `$`.